# Way to fix glitches on expanding boxes? HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, z-index

So I'm building my first real website and I have a services section with boxes and when the user hovers over the box, it expands and describes the service. I'm a newbie and have been struggling a lot with this. I have a solution that I think would fix all of my problems in one go, but I am having trouble executing it.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #212529;
}

a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #8E3029;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.font-primary {
  font-family: "Open", sans-serif;
}

section {
  padding: 40px 0px 40px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section-bg {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.section-bg2 {
  background-color: #c6c6c6;
}

.section-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.section-title h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #000000;
}

.section-title p {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
}

.section-title p::after,
{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #8E3029;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
}

#items {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.item {
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 29px 0 rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.1);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #212529;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #8E3029;
  color: #212529;
  width: 25%;
  border-right: solid 5px #8E3029;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item h4 {
  color: white;
}

.item:hover {
  height: fit-content;
  width: 37%;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- ======= Services Section ======= -->
<section id="services" class="services section-bg">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>Services</h2>
      <p>Check out what we can do for you</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Distribution</h4>
      <br> MDT Distribution will provide your organization’s need for:
      <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
        <li>Branded Prime resin</li>
        <li>Generic Prime resin as our Tech Resin® certified grade</li>
        <li>Virgin Wide-spec resin selected to match your needs</li>
        <li>Reprocessed or Semi-finished resin for your recycled material requirement.</li>
      </ul>
      We can supply resin delivered to your doorstep or make it available for pickup from multiple regional warehouses around the country.
      <br><br> MDT leverages our supply relationships around the country, we purchase in quantity from these sources, and then offer you resin costs to fit your project needs.
      <br>
      <br>
      <span style="font-weight: bolder;">Services include:</span>
      <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
        <li>Railcar purchase and delivery</li>
        <li>Railcar spotting and unloading into bulk trucks or boxed truckloads</li>
        <li>Truckload ordering from large volume sources</li>
        <li>Material searches for your unique needs</li>
        <li>Providing analytical data on all your deliveries.</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Custom Compounding</h4>

      <br>
      <span style="font-weight: bolder;">Off Grade / Wide-spec Resin:</span>
      <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
        <li>Our MDT Replas facility is a production and distribution facility for virgin and recycled resins.</li>
        <li>OG/Wide-spec resins are non-prime resins, outside of the specific Prime spec ranges.</li>
        <li>MDT can produce a wide variety of custom compounded and blended resins within consistent specifications to meet our processors’ requirements.</li>
        <li>Prices offered will generally provide an advantage over prime resin usage.</li>
        <li>MDT Replas has rail access, large silo capacity, and its own bulk truck fleet to serve customers in our region.</li>
        <li>The laboratory and quality team at MDT Replas will perform ASTM testing services for your initial qualification process and ongoing delivery certification requirements.</li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <span style="font-weight: bolder;">Reprocessed Resin:</span>
      <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
        <li>Both our MDT recycled resin facilities offer compounding and distribution of custom and standard MDT Repro grades.</li>
        <li>These facilities offer full-service recycling of both post-consumer and post-industrial scrap.</li>
        <li>Material conversion processes available are compounding, blending, shredding/grinding, and densifying of recycled scrap.</li>
        <li>Standard grades offer high volume cost advantages while special formulations and toll processing fit your unique program requirements.</li>
        <li>Customers experience cost savings through the use of post-industrial and post-consumer recycled scrap turned into recycled resins available at a discount to the cost of prime resins.</li>
        <li>MDT Bromley provides rail, bulk truck, and boxed load products.</li>
        <li>Full-scale ASTM laboratory testing and analysis is provided by our quality technicians for your initial qualification and ongoing delivery certification requirements.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="padding-top:1.5em">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Material Conversion / Toll Processing</h4>

      <br> MDT resin recycling facilities offer complete material conversion services to the recycled resin industry.
      <br><br> We offer scrap conversion of Polypropylene, HDPE and TPO materials into useful customer end-products.
      <br><br> Our conversion processes include:
      <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
        <li>Scrap material shredding</li>
        <li>Grinding, as primary or secondary particle size reduction</li>
        <li>Material densification</li>
        <li>Scrap washing & separation</li>
        <li>Extrusion (pelletizing)</li>
      </ul>
      MDT will deliver partial material conversion product or fully pelletized product to meet your needs.
      <br><br> If the scrap that you purchase or generate is not in the form you operation needs, please contact MDT to receive the necessary material conversion.</div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Post Blending</h4>
      <br>Post blending is a process where both compounded OG/Wide-spec or Pelletized recycled resin lots are uniformly mixed so that the spec-range of the delivered product is consistent throughout the entire load.
      <br><br> MDT’s large OG/Wide-spec silos can blend railcar-sized loads at one time.
      <br><br> Recycled resin lots are post-blended prior to final bagging or box-out.
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Packaging & Logistics</h4>
      <br>MDT’s resin distribution business supplies customers from numerous sites throughout North America.
      <br><br>Our nationwide network of material warehouses can receive large bulk deliveries of resin and distribute it to your location in either bulk or full boxed truckload quantities
      <br><br>MDT’s Replas facility in Houston and our Bromley facility in North Carolina will prepare your deliveries for shipment in either bulk truck, full boxload truck, or in your railcars.
      <br><br>MDT Replas has its own bulk truck fleet to serve customers in its region.
      <br><br>Our professional Materials Management department will organize your entire shipment process or coordinate with your facility for receiving dock times for your pickups.
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="padding-top:1.5em">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Technical Support Services</h4>
      <br>MDT’s Tech Support team will provide you with:
      <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
        <li>Quality assurance support services</li>
        <li>Resin selection and evaluation</li>
        <li>On-location problem solving and troubleshooting</li>
        <li>Process optimization</li>
        <li>Sample testing</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="padding-top:1.5em">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Laboratory Analysis and Material R&D:</h4>
      <br>MDT’s ASTM laboratories in both Houston, TX and Fletcher, NC provide full inspection reports for all incoming and outgoing loads.

      <br><br>Material R&D projects can help develop new compounded resin formulas for your product applications.

      <br><br><span style="font-weight: bolder;">With two physical and analytical laboratories, MDT offers testing of:</span>
      <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
        <li>Material characterization and certification</li>
        <li>Melt flow index</li>
        <li>Izod impact</li>
        <li>FTIR spectroscopy</li>
        <li>Flex & Tensile testing</li>
        <li>Density analysis</li>
        <li>Moisture content measurement</li>
        <li>Colorimetric analysis & color matching</li>
        <li>PE/PP content measurement</li>
        <li>Ash Content</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="padding-top:1.5em">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Sustainable Resin Programs</h4>
      <br><span style="font-weight: bolder">Phoenix Pro Certified PCR-PP resins: </span>
      <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
        <li>Available from both MDT Replas and MDT Bromley locations.</li>
        <li>Post-Consumer recycled plastic material</li>
        <li>Natural, Black & White Repro Grades</li>
        <li>Certified by AM Testing & Services, an ISO/IEC 17025:2017 laboratory</li>
        <li>PhoenixPro PCR-PP meets requirements of ISOº14021:2016</li>
        <li>Association of Plastic Recyclers (APR) PCR Certification Program</li>
        <li>Continuing certification based upon quarterly data submissions to AM Testing laboratory</li>
      </ul>
      <span style="font-weight: bolder">Replas & Bromley ReNew PIR-PP resins:</span>
      <ul>
        <li>A wide range of Extruded grades
        </li>
        <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
          <li>Available with Certified recycled content by SCS Global Services
          </li>
          <li>Multiple material conversion options</li>
          <li>Custom compounding</li>
          <li>Black, White & Mixed color options</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Multiple logistics options</li>
        <ul style="font-weight:lighter">
          <li>Bulk Truck</li>
          <li>Super Sacks</li>
          <li>Gaylord Box delivery</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">FDA Approved Resins</h4>
      <br>Both our MDT Replas and MDT Bromley facilities offer FDA food-grade approved resin materials
      <br><br>MDT has received verified PNC letters from the FDA’s Center for Food Safety and Applied Nutrition.
      <br><br>FDA PIR-PP resins are available as natural, white, and black pellets.
      <br><br>Use of MDT FDA grades are approved for food contact articles, up to 100% recycled content.
      <br><br>The FDA has approved these food grade resins for all Conditions of Use, A through J.
      <br><br>Approved additives are allowed in our FDA grade resin materials.
      <br><br>These resins also carry certification by SCS Global Services as certified recycled content material.
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<!-- End Services Section -->
```

I am unsure if I formatted this properly. If I did not, here is the link to it on codepen: https://codepen.io/DiKi777/pen/JjZgGrM

I originally had coded this using flexbox, but removed it because I could only get it working without it.

I then had an issue where if you hover over the last box it would expand and then glitch because once it got to a certain size it would need to go onto a new row and your mouse would no longer be hovering over the box. I got around that by customizing the width precisely so that it works for all the boxes (This method would eventually require going in and making different code based on different screen sizes which I realize is very inefficient).

The other issue is that if I hover over the first box, then the others move, and if I try to expand another box, they all return to their original position as soon as you stop hovering over the first box and your mouse is in a completely wrong position.

I was thinking an elegant solution to all my problems would be to have the box expand on top of all the others without affecting the position of the other boxes, but when I try putting in a higher z-index for (item:hover) in my CSS it doesn't seem to actually have any effect.

If I could get the solution working, I'd probably set up a grid system based on screen size or see if I can get it working in flexbox.

Comment: Are you looking for a tooltip?

Comment: Oh. Yes! I could probably make that work, thank you so much for the direction